# How to store checked box API values and display in <span> HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: CheckboxImageExample]

I need assistance in storing checkbox API values.  I have multiple checkboxes and I can display API values in html  when checkbox is checked.  But how do I store the initial value of a checked checkbox and show it in a span?

I currently get “on” value instead of API initial value.

eg. The value I want is “Faculty Lecture” as stored in the API

Below is my code:

```js
//store checkbox values
$('#myCheck1').on('change', function() {
  $('.results').html(this.checked ? this.value : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" name="checks" class="round">

<span id="eventTitle" class="results"></span>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: Meaning of Checkbox API value is unclear to me. Please explain more. Also where is this ‘Breakfast Event’ value?

Comment: I want to store the selected values that appear on the right of the screen shot and display them in a <span> element. (I have attached the screen shot named "checkboxImageExample")

Comment: Why isn't that in the HTML snippet?

Comment: I have put the correct value. I want to store "Faculty Lecture" or "Lunch" and display that.

Comment: This is not clear: ***I currently get “on” value instead of API initial value instead of "on" value.*** What do you mean?

Comment: @PeterKA, I meant when trying to store the value I currently get “on” results instead of API initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get value attached to checkbox. 
You should use `<label>` instead of `<span>` with input checkbox to show its value initially.

Example

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" name="checks" class="round">
 <label for="myCheck1">Faculty Lecture</label>
```

You can get label of checkbox in jquery like

```
$("label[for='myCheck1']")
```

To get label text you can use following:

```
$("label[for='myCheck1']").text()
```

Following should be your html and jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" name="checks" class="round">
 <label for="myCheck1">Faculty Lecture</label>
 <span class='results'></span>

<script>

//store checkbox values
$('#myCheck1').on('change', function() {
var lb=$("label[for='myCheck1']").text();
  $('.results').html(lb);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the checkbox `value` attribute to store the value of the checkbox, e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" name="checks" class="round" value="Faculty Lecture">
```

That way `this.value` returns `"Faculty Lecture"`

Also, use the class in your selector instead of the id of the element by changing:

```
$('#myCheck1').on('change', function() { ....
```

To:

```
$('.round').on('change', function() { .....
```